# In backbone can I refresh with window.location.replace( document.URL )

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to refresh the page and in particular, whatever the current view on the page must be re-rendered.
Is it okay to write

```
window.location.replace(document.URL);
```

instead of playing around with Backbone.history.fragment as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901574/how-to-refresh-a-page-in-a-backbone-application)

Answer (score 0):

why not use:

```
 window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.reload()` but that would reload and render everything. If you are using HTML5 pushsate you might be better off using `Backbone.history.navigate()` to avoid re-executing scripts such as Backbone.js

Comment: Good point. Is there an event I can fire that would cause the router to act on the current route ? (thereby triggering a refresh without reload of backbone)

Comment: Backbone.history.navigate(Backbone.history.fragment, {trigger: true})

Answer (score 0):

okay I've found an answer, it was in the middle of one of Thomas Davis's videos.

```
var app = new Router;
app.trigger('route:mypage');
```

This will re-call the route thereby causing all view's associated with that route to re-render. Essentially a 'soft' page refresh without reloading backbone or other libraries.